# Serving HTML5 Application via Golang

Tags: html, heroku, go

I recently made a golang application and hosted it on Heroku, and I'd like to serve my HTML5 via the golang net/http router (at "/serv"), The server is working well, but when I type in:

```
http.ServeFile(w, r, "html/index.html")
```

The page loads and the name of my html app appears, but the app doesn't load and it basically stays as a black screen.

My html5 application looks like this in (localhost)
[Here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtmCw.png)

And my file directory for the html5 application is
[Here,,,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Sbp.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set up a handler to serve exactly one file, but you apparently don't have anything set up to serve anything other than the file at `html/index.html`.  You probably want to set up a file server for the entire directory:

```
http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./html")))
```

Comment: How would I then block access to the pictures, the javascript files and the general source of the application?

Comment: You don't.  That's how the internet works - if you want javascript to run in the browser, you have to give them the javascript.  If you want a picture to show up in the browser, you have to give them the picture.

Comment: I surely don't mind that but, I don't want people to be able to access my files via / by just typing the filename, I want all calls to / to redirect to the index.html unless it's a call from the app itself